# How to run multiple files at the same time in a vps?

Tags: python-3.x, vps, discord.py

I'm wondering how to run multiple files (py discord bot files) at the same time on 1 Linux vps. What's the best way for this?

Comment: Create services for them and have the service manager handle them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `screen` command (if available) to create multiple windows, and have a bot run on each window

If you don't know how to use `screen`, you create a window with `screen -S <screen name>`. To disconnect from the window, but still leave it running in the background,  press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, and then press <kbd>d</kbd>. Finally, to reconnect to a screen, use `screen -rd <screen name>`.

For a more in depth tutorial on how to use screen, visit https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/